# WordPress changes some option by itself

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm editing a WP template in order to fit my requirements. I firstly installed WP on a temporary server and then moved (files + DB) to the new server (without reinstallation).

Now, I'm almost done, but sometimes it happen that the logo has changes, and some menu disappears. If I look at the database I discover that in 'wp_option' table, all value where url should be www.newserver.com reverted to the old www.oldserver.com

How does is this possible? How can I fix this? Is there something I should know before going on?

thanks

Comment: when you migrated the files/db over did you perfom SQL queries to `UPDATE` all the existing URLs to reference `www.newserver.com`?  Wordpress is not magic so when you switch the domain you have to manually go in to the DB and perform various `UPDATE` queries to change all references of `oldserver.com` to `newserver.com`, there are some plugins that claim to do this but i've never had any success

Comment: sure, all of them!! I even exported the db->updated->imported but sometimes this mess happens

Comment: did you change the values in your `wp-config.php` file? if they still have the old server address then its likely that they overwrote the db entries with the old server address when you migrated

Comment: I don't have the old server url in wp-config.php or wp-settings.php

Comment: hmm...not sure how it happened then but it should be a pretty easy fix, just edit the appropriate values in the the DB

Comment: That is what I do celeriko, but after some times, they get overwritten, and I can't understand where the new datas come from.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily overcome this problem just go to
Dashboard-> settings-> general and replace wordpress address (url) and site address(url) with your domains url.

But prior to this setting you must change the value in wp_options table of option_name ->siteurl in database to your new siteurl or else it wont be possible for you to login into the dashboard of your site on server as unchanged siteurl will keep on redirecting you to localhost.

wordpress url shoud contain path to your wordpress folder whereas site address will be your domains name.

You came across this problem because you migrated your local's database onto the server and in the wp_options table the siteurl is still the same representing your local siteurl. This needs to be updated as mentioned above.

Wordpress stores the siteurl and address of wordpress folder in wp_options table to make functions like bloginfo ("siteurl")
to work properly  and give you site address independent of changes.

Comment: I always edit the DB replacing the old url with the new one. I don't have the "siteurl" enabled in wp_option, so I don't think this could be the source of the problem. I will try to enable the "siteurl" in the wp_option file and see what happens